# c - simple pointer query, initializing a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm kinda confused:

```
int* p=1000;
printf("%d\n", (int)(p+sizeof(int))); // what is going on here?
```

does `p` point to `1000` or does p = the memory address `1000`? If it is the former, could this be achieved  achieved like this:

```
int dummyVariable = 1000;
int * p = &dummyVariable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration

```
int* p=1000;
```

makes `p` *point* to the address `1000`.

While in the case of

```
int dummyVariable = 1000;
int * p = &dummyVariable;
```

you initialize `dummyVariable` to the value `1000` and make `p` point to `dummyVariable`.

---

Another way to look at it:

In the first case you have

```
          Address 1000
          |
          v
+---+     +-----+
| p | --> | ??? |
+---+     +-----+
```

And in the second case you have

```
          Address &dummyVariable
          |
          v
+---+     +----------------------------+
| p | --> | dummyVariable (value 1000) |
+---+     +----------------------------+
```

---

A third way of looking at it, is that the value of `p` is an integer (that just happens to be an address). In the first case `p` contains the value `1000`, i.e. it's pointing to the address `1000`.

In the second case the contents of `p` is `&dummyVariable`, i.e. it points to the location in memory where `dummyVariable` is stored.

---

As for the printout in the first example giving you the value `1016`, that's because of how pointer arithmetic works: Whatever you add to a pointer is multiplied by the size of the base type. So if you have a pointer to `int`, then everything you add to that pointer will be multiplied by `sizeof int`.

In your case, the size of `int` is `4` bytes, so what you are doing is actually `1000 + 4 * 4` which is equal to `1016`.

Comment: if this is the case, and p points to address 1000, and we dont know what stored there, how come the evaluation of the print statement is 1016 (on my machine)

Comment: @dgamma3 Because dereferencing the pointer in that case leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It may give you the value `1016`, it may give you some other value, it may crash your program, or it may even cause the operating system to crash.

Comment: This is on a university exam test paper, i dont think he would do that.
would this extra information help: This system uses 4byte integers? (that was attached to the question)

Comment: @dgamma3 Actually, you're not really *dereferencing* the pointer, you just print the value of the pointer after some pointer arithmetic. And pointer arithmetic works as follows: It multiplies the size of the base type (`int` in your case) to what you add to the pointer, in this case it multiplies `sizeof(int)` with your addition (`sizeof(int)`) giving the result of `16`, and `1000 + 16` is `1016`.

Comment: sizeof(int) == 4? (where is 16 from)? so your saying:
p+sizeof(int) = address 1000 + sizeof(int)

Comment: @dgamma3 No, I'm saying that `pointer + X` will give you the address `pointer + (sizeof(*pointer) * X)`. Pointer arithmetic like this is also the base of how array indexing works.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `p` is *storing* the memory address `1000`, whatever that memory address is holding. In fact, `p` resides at another memory address, which, again stores the number `1000`, which is a memory address, etc. Your second example is correct: The pointer `p` is assigned the memory address of `dummyVariable`, now if you modify `dummyVariable` or the `*p` (dereferencing the pointer), the changes will be applied to both (because they point to the same memory space).

Answer (score 0):

```
int* p=1000;
```

p is a pointer pointing to memory location 1000.

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(p+sizeof(int)));
```

You are trying to access some memory here.( 1000 + sizeof(int))
Directly assigning some random address to a pointer as done here is not a good idea.
You should have got below mentioned warnings:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

The second part:

```
int dummyVariable = 1000;
int * p = &dummyVariable;
```

Here 1000 is a value and pointer `p` is pointing to a memory location holding 1000.
So both are diffrent.

Comment: @dgamma3 No some compilers throw the above mentioned warnings